# C++ Structure to C#

Tags: c#, struct

I have the following C++ structure.

```
typedef struct  CallbackStru
{
    UINT16 type;                /*type of callback*/
    void *func;                 /*callback function*/
}CallbackStru, *tCallbackStru;
```

I need to convert this to C# and I've ended up with this.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CallbackStructure
{
    public ushort type;
    public object func;
}
```

When using this conversion in a callback, the callback does not fire. I have a feeling it's because of the structure I have and more specifically the conversion of **void *func;** to **object func;**. Is this the proper way of doing this?

Cheers.

Comment: 1. a void pointer is not a function pointer. It would rather translate as `IntPtr` in the c# struct.

Comment: It is not the proper way.  You must declare a delegate that matches the *real* function pointer type.  Whatever it might be, unguessable from that shoddy C++ declaration.